# Como fazer para Item só aparecer quando código da categoria = 1

Tags: java, jsf

possuo o seguinte codigo

```
<h:selectOneRadio value="#{solicitacaoImpressaoBean.entrega.tipoGuia}" class="tipoGuia">
    <f:selectItems value="#{solicitacaoImpressaoBean.tipoGuia}" var="guia" 
                itemLabel="#{guia.descricao}" itemValue="#{guia}" />
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

que faz o seguinte :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

gostaria de quando o código da categoria fosse 1 não renderizasse o item que é embargo

algo do tipo

```
rendered="#{not solicitacaoImpressaoBean.entrega.peg.categoria.codigo eq 1}"
```

mas como fazer isso em um selectOneRadio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

consegui dasabilitar o item fazendo itemDisabled="#{solicitacaoImpressaoBean.entrega.peg.categor‌​ia.codigo eq 1 and guia.codigo eq 3}"

```
com css <style> .tipoGuia input:disabled , .tipoGuia input:disabled ~ label {display:none} </style>
```

sumi com o item em questão.

Answer (score 0):

Uma forma simples de fazer isso é na construção que retorna a lista de tipoGuia, no BackBean você pode verificar que a categoria é 1 e não incluir embargo na lista.

Para fazer isso na parte da tela poderia usar selectItem (ao invés do selectItems) e (assumindo que são apenas 3) poderia colocar o itemDisabled usando a condição de categoria de forma semelhante ao rendered:

```
 <f:selectItem itemValue="2" itemLabel="embargo" itemDisabled="#{not solicitacaoImpressaoBean.entrega.peg.categoria.codigo eq 1}" />
```

Comment: <f:selectItem itemValue="2" itemLabel="embargo" itemDisabled="#{solicitacaoImpressaoBean.entrega.peg.categoria.codigo eq 1}" /> realmente desabilita o item, mas eu gostaria de sumir com ele, ou seja não renderizar na página.

Comment: E não poderia não enviar essa opção na lista de selectItems? Essa foi minha primeira sugestão, resolveria no back-end.

Comment: Como faria isso com um Enum?

Comment: Não estava documentado que você estava usando um Enum :) eu imaginei que fosse talvez um List. Vamos dar um passo atrás. Esse requisito de não renderizar a opção embargo caso a categoria seja "1" é funcional ou apenas de tela? Se for funcional acho que talvez o caminho seja rever na modelagem para que cada Categoria possa indicar as opções com as quais pode se relacionar. Mas claro que estou sugerindo isso para você avaliar, não conheço o modelo para saber se é viável.

Comment: consegui dasabilitar o item fazendo itemDisabled="#{solicitacaoImpressaoBean.entrega.peg.categoria.codigo eq 1 and guia.codigo eq 3}" agora estou tentando fazer ele sumir via css .

O input consegui mas o label ainda mostra com .tipoGuia input:disabled {display:none}

Comment: consegui com css 

<style>
   .tipoGuia input:disabled , .tipoGuia input:disabled ~ label {display:none}
  </style>

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda.